# Weird stretching when moving main bone

Tags: rigging

I've just finished rigging a fish, however I've noticed that if I move the main bone I get weird stretching on one small part, it **does** move but very little and it basically just stretches out.

I don't think it is a weight paint problem as I just tried painting the whole fish red for that one bone and I still got that weird stretching.

Anyone has any idea what the issue can be?

[image]

File: https://blend-exchange.com/b/YyVWrZvB

Comment: maybe select this vertex in Edit mode and assign it to the correct vertex group?

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots Just did, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some vertices are part of the vertex group called *Root* but I guess *Root* is not supposed to control vertices, you need to disable its *Deform* option and parent the body to the armature again:

[image]

Comment: Yes it's so logical now. I actually just removed all weight from the root bone and it works fine now, thank you!